# Apostrophes use in possessive forms

Tags: apostrophe

Would it be correct to use an apostrophe in this sentence:

> High variations in dogs' diet may induce health issues.

Comment: *High **variability** in **a dog's** diet may induce health issues.*

Answer (score 2):

dogs' diets, with an s on both. Not all dogs have the same diet.

Boys' games; girls' dresses. You have to have a plural noun otherwise it means there is just one and that is not the meaning.

Do you really mean variation?

Comment: thank you. Maybe variability as proposed by FumbleFingers is better. I have to check.

Comment: @Leon-Alph Too much variety in a dog's diet, not variation, not variability.